# Bulk load Roles - is it possible?

Tags: salesforce

Is it possible to bulk load Roles?  We have more than 100 roles that have to be created and doing them through the standard UI will be quite time consuming.  I assume it can be done through custom Apex or using the API but is there any way to do it with the tools provided by Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse or ant migration tool for management Roles.
More details you can find by the following links

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/daas_package.htm

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index.htm

```
for Eclipse:
 1. create a project and connect it to you org
 2. add needed roles to project
```

[image]